# How to draw pattern by adb input touchscreen swipe?

Tags: android, input, adb, swipe, touchscreen

"adb shell input touchscreen swipe 500 500 1000 1000" draw only straight line

Is there any way to draw line such as 'L' or 'N'  at once ?

Thanks

Comment: have you checked my answer? Is it worked for you?

Answer (score 2):

After doing some research on google, I got one solution using **getevent** and **sendevent** commands.

**getevent**

Using get event command you have to record the events for your swipe pattern. This can be done using below command.

```
adb shell getevent | find "event1"
```

Run above command and do swiping in your phone. The above command will generate some set of events. You better to write that data into a file, because produces 300 to 500 lines.

Once the recording is done, the file will look like below

```
/dev/input/event1: 0003 0039 00000099
/dev/input/event1: 0001 014a 00000001
/dev/input/event1: 0001 0145 00000001
/dev/input/event1: 0003 0035 000001a0
/dev/input/event1: 0003 0036 00000655
/dev/input/event1: 0003 0030 00000005
/dev/input/event1: 0003 0031 00000005
/dev/input/event1: 0000 0000 00000000
/dev/input/event1: 0003 0035 000001a1
/dev/input/event1: 0003 0030 00000006
-------------------------------------
-------------------------------------
```

In the above file, the last 2 columns are in hexadecimal format. You need to convert them into decimal format. You can write some utility tool to convert them to decimal format. Once you convert them to decimal format now you have to use sendevent command

**sendevent**
Now construct below commands using sendevent.

```
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event1 0003 57 153
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event1 0001 330 1
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event1 0001 325 1
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event1 0003 53 416
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event1 0003 54 1621
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event1 0003 48 5
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event1 0003 49 5
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event1 0000 0 0
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event1 0003 53 417
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event1 0003 48 6
-----------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------
```

If you see last 3 columns, the first column is same as getevet column, and last two are decimal equivalent to getevent last 2 columns.

Now if you run above commands in a batch file, the recorded pattern will be drawn on the screen.

Comment: https://github.com/woosuk0410/test/blob/master/Sample.mp4  plz check this url I have tried aleary but  sendevent command isn't available to unlock pattern I think...

Comment: https://github.com/woosuk0410/test/blob/master/sendevent.txt this is what I did (position is correct I have checked)